# Can I write a <script> tag inside a <script> tag

Tags: javascript, html

This is my code. I'm trying to stop running an external js file when screen width is less than 1025.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var gdsize = 1025;          
if(window.innerWidth>=gdsize) {

    <script>
    window.cookieconsent_options = {"message":"\"Geek Dashboard uses cookies to make sure you get the best experience on our website.\" -","dismiss":"It's OK","learnMore":"More Details Here","link":"http://www.geekdashboard.com/cookies/","theme":"dark-bottom"};
    }
    </script>


</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cookieconsent2/1.0.9/cookieconsent.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The usual script tag (type text/javascript) is used to embed js inside markup. The tag itself is not valid js, so you cannot nest script tags (unless it's in an opaque context, such as a string).

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
var gdsize = 1025;          
if(window.innerWidth>=gdsize) {

  
    window.cookieconsent_options = {"message":"\"Geek Dashboard uses cookies to make sure you get the best experience on our website.\" -","dismiss":"It's OK","learnMore":"More Details Here","link":"http://www.geekdashboard.com/cookies/","theme":"dark-bottom"};
    }
  

</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cookieconsent2/1.0.9/cookieconsent.min.js"></script>

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/024d498L/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why would you use a nested script to modify an object property?

It can be solved in a much simpler way since you're already "in the script":

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var gdsize = 1025;          
  if(window.innerWidth>=gdsize) {

    window.cookieconsent_options = {"message":"\"Geek Dashboard uses cookies to make sure you get the best experience on our website.\" -","dismiss":"It's OK","learnMore":"More Details Here","link":"http://www.geekdashboard.com/cookies/","theme":"dark-bottom"};

  }    
</script>
```

Answer (score 15):

```
<script type="text/x-jQuery-tmpl">
    var gdsize = 1025;          
    if(window.innerWidth>=gdsize) {

    <script type="text/javascript">
        <!-- Some javascript here -->
        window.cookieconsent_options = {"message":"\"Geek Dashboard uses cookies to make sure you get the best experience on our website.\" -","dismiss":"It's OK","learnMore":"More Details Here","link":"http://www.geekdashboard.com/cookies/","theme":"dark-bottom"};
        }
    {{html "</sc"+"ript>"}}
</script>
```

You can use `{{html "</sc"+"ript>"}}` in place of `</script>`

**Explanation [update]:**

When you use a `</script>` HTML tag inside a quoted (literal) string, the tag is treated as a closing tag rather than as a portion of the string. So you cannot directly use the `</script>` tag inside a script section.

One work-around is to escape the `</script>` tags and/or split up the `<script>` tags:

```
var scriptEnd = "</scr" + "ipt>";
document.write(scriptEnd);
```

Comment: What's the explanation for the type on the outer script element?

Comment: @Vikrant Your code didn't worked for me. When I place that code in my wp_head() it resets the theme settings after hitting save. Maybe it is a theme issue.

Comment: `var scriptEnd = "<\scr" + "ipt>"; ` should be `var scriptEnd = "</scr" + "ipt>"; ` (You used backslash instead of forwardslash.) (also thank you very helpful!)

Answer (score 0):

I forced write a SRC atribute into SCRIPT tag, is a similar mode for write a SCRIPT tag into a SCRIPT tag. This script forced to reload a JS file every moment than load a page, prevent cache with use version ramdom number into url. Work fine, load a JS file ok:

```html
    <div id="jsgenrandom"><script type="text/javascript"></script></div>
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var divjs = document.getElementById('jsgenrandom')
        var divjss = divjs.getElementsByTagName("SCRIPT")[0].src = "https://_route_/the_js.js?v="+ Math.floor(Math.random()*1000) + ""  
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Write with Javascript inside a SCRIPT tag with this solution. Work Fine:

```html
<div id="writeintoscript"><script type="text/javascript"></script></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var writeintoscripts = document.getElementById('writeintoscript')
writeintoscripts.getElementsByTagName("SCRIPT")[0].innerHTML = "alert('WRITE INTO SCRIPT TAG WITH JAVASCRIPT')"
</script>
```