# External JS not working on div inside a script balise

Tags: javascript, html

So i'm using a RowTemplate for a KendoGrid looking like that (Kendo is a javascript library but not really important for this post) :

```html
<script id="techLangTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-tmpl">
    <tr data-uid="#: uid #">
        <td class="name">#: name#</td>
        <td class="vote">
            <div class="starrr"></div>
        </td>
        <td class="actions"></td>
    </tr>
</script>
```

The thing is I would like to work with an external JS file doing his work on my **starrr** div and it isn't working, I guess it's because it's inside a  balise and it has to stay there.

If there is a way to move this code to a JS file maybe that's gonna work, don't know how to do that cause of **id** & **type** attributes.

Any tip for me ?

Comment: I hope it helps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33969544/can-i-write-a-script-tag-inside-a-script-tag

Comment: My problem is solved ty